# How can I view a raw text file on GitHub permanently?

Tags: github

How can I view a raw text file on GitHub?

I created an unlisted REPO and inside the repo is a text file.

When I view it in raw format I get exactly what I want. And if I use C# to Download the text of that page, I get what I want.

My only concern is that the link to the github raw file is

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USERNAME/STUFF/master/version.txt?token=THETOKEN

Does the `THETOKEN` part ever change? Like can I use this link for the rest of my life to access that raw text file? Or does the link change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The token part is an auth token so it will work as long as that set of credentials is valid (until you revoke it). However, you should still manage that token as a secret.

If you plan to share this C# program with others you should *not* share your token with them, since this will give them access to other parts of your GitHub account.

If you want to share this file publicly you should publish it to a public CDN or another service that provides access control. For example you can use [Amazon S3 with signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) for a few cents a month.

Comment: Using a PAT does not work for me. How can I create such a token?